# Can I select record in MYSQL: Sorted according to the date/time created, even if table dont have date/time stamp in it?

Tags: mysql

I want to sort records in my table according to the date/time created.
But i don't have any data/time stamp column in my table. 
Is there a way in which i can still select records according to the date/time created or modified???
I am using `MYSQL`. 
I tried `SELECT * from user ORDER BY created_at` but this also not working.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Short answer:No.Unless somehow the records in your table can be joined to some other table which has a time field related logically.

Comment: I dont know even i can do it not, because When I am searching on Google, i could not find any answer. I tried searching Google in by writing different queries but they all the "select" statement tutorials in those tutorials i could not find any answer...

Comment: A lesson for better db design in the future.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO : i dont think this question any piece of Code...

Comment: @Mihai can you please look at the answer given by user876345 , if something is possible... and yeah sure it is a lesson for a better DB design :)

Comment: No,he thought you have a date field named created_at.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41807/room-for-cyberboy-and-mihai

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41813/discussion-between-cyberboy-and-mihai)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other commenters have pointed out, the short answer is no.  MySQL doesn't allow you to sort by the time at which a record was created unless you have explicitly stored that value in the database.  Here's a possible way out for the future:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX created_at (created_at);
```

Then your future INSERT queries will add a NOW() argument to populate the created_at column.

If you do that, then when you retrieve records, if they have a "created at" value equal to the default, you'll know the record was created before you modified your INSERT query.  You could go through and manually update those records, or assign them all today's date for simplicity.